# How to allow a function return type undefined

Tags: typescript, undefined, void

I think that typescript has many unobvious places, making it not strict and not correct.

I want use undefined as functions return type. Because in reality it is undefined, not void or some other fictional type. But when I write this:

```
function myFunction(): undefined {
    
}
```

it says "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value".

It must not. And everyone can verify this. I don't want to agree with "void is better, we decided that promise equal undefined" and so on. And don't want to write `return undefined`, if it is obvious and redundant.

How to make it work in this example? May be some flag exist or some "miracle comment instruction"?

Here is the use case, explaining why I want explicit undefined:

[Wrong example with an issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=54&pln=3&pc=1#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBnRBbApgQTQJ4wBiUcSkAFAJQBcKACgE5bxrYA8AbovACYA+FAG9gASCbZY4JqkjYA7oxaY22SjXo9+KALxDRYse1gAVeDkThYG6vsNHYACxZKAokxZNKAcgAyiIgA1igAhrAo0MgYADbYAHQouDExKAAOLNDYaGgobCiw2EyqkOHYfCgAtChkoeAA5k4R2AAeWWkIyPE+1ADc4mIAvgA0KACMAAxTKH3ig7ODIAD0SygA4oEVMfAARkyhTARgZJ2oGDh+u-uHAMqhBGgAkrAASlIykGgAarx8lCgQSD0Gj6FDaCp0MG-ETiSTSWQAqA0fqLY4wU4oTAEUjoiiaKE6YQoFYoDiVckoR4oBTwFIFJzwSAhZzhFBwj4FAhpbB5XLg0ZUml0yCICIxQIhRlofjYcQkgASRR5VOcjOZTlZ2C4RQIqsg9V5KAA8gBpUZOJWUtnvBHg2E2s5YbCXPYHAh3B7PN7wz4-fj-c54QgkE4UGYo5arRWSK3QUKQHwRKKQWAsVKwLnZUbwCL5EURLGRRB8HnxipUvjIRMoIIipQKDW53JSmVo8jIdBOl3XAj-A71YF2ITgmb0SDgTA7IowsTwUD-DPcxCgMJMeo0PS6XQoHyIHYAK2wcB8Mwc7IRADlQhfesTVjdudB4KFUphQvV4NAQlBa4gFKg43YOYQAkB1xgAJgAZgjYA4giFoxwnKcmD0TsLiuN1-ixHF21QWZgGTWIEnFdcWnwklyUoqjKJQAARKwdjiAFQlpKoUCvC8wkgCpCmKRlwjDABCYSQBAIA)

[Correct example with a solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBnRBbApgQTQJ4wBiUcSkAFAJQBcKACgE5bxrYA8AbovACYA%20FAG9gASCbZY4JqkjYA7oxaY22SjXo9%20KALxDRYse1gAVeDkThYG6vsNHYACxZKAokxZNKAcgAyiIgA1igAhrAo0MgYADbYAHQouDExKAAOLNDYaGgobCiw2EyqkOHYfCgAtChkoeAA5k4R2AAeWWkIyPE%201ADc4mIAvgA0KACMAAxTKH3ig7ODIAD0SygA4oEVMfAARkyhTARgZJ2oGDh%20u-uHAMqhBGgAkrAASlIykGgAarx8lCgQSD0Gj6FDaCp0MG-ETiSTSWQAqA0fqLY4wU4oTAEUjoiiaGqQPjYUDweQVYQoFYoDiVWkoAByiCUjzCmHQMmwo2c4TyEXyrVCcBiBAJRJJZMSAHVHvSUJQxtQUABCFWq1XiKkACSK2BQLOcpJC3OaXCKBANkHqeVyAHkANKjJw6vUoOEfKH8WHvBHg9BYbCXPYHAh3B7PN7wz4-fj-c54QgkE4UGa9SmrGl0xnMlAKeApHNMeCFSKITzYOCu72QKUyuUAJkVaqbwFRVIAwshYPsK9gAI7gUKpWCITHYpPINHkZBhSCIZxFACyY9xyElRacpidaDuOA7kC7gpskKgYtJ5RhYipjMrkcSbhah9FxLPfHiLeWq21khd0FCkB8ERRPuLBDgQaTZKMRbWigs4RFiJZEjOFQsnwyAASgQSzkoChODy%20Skmg-DYJOGJxoG1wEP8Bz1MCdhCL6kKQOAmA7EUF7wKA-ywGB2CIKAYRMPUNB6LougoD4iA7AAVuWsA%20DMDhugi9KhPSqZUjc4HQPAg6YqE9TwNAIRQJhTKoL%207BzCAEhVuMdYAMwoiAcQRH%20BA2qApgKIgOJTp8Lx-qhmC0aCJ7PmSegznOTpMEuvmnGuzibtkO7YHuB5wP0wAuSgLT0ExLFsWJZFXMGVGQO5nnefFFBoAFhJYCmabUrS1S0MAV5Mi6oRsmgHJcrhEQGrk2xBocOZ5qk9RSE%204rnqEoCFEwAn1Mx2D7pEg4xMMHWrCy0BOkZBROPkyC6ggOBIRN%20byKay3Ta5qBsH1uqksduoQPCCS7Sg0qypQ9mNk26rAEBsQJDEiBCS0swgHDQA)

Comment: This behaviour can be customized via the `tsconfig.json` file, by setting `noImplicitReturns` to `false`.

Comment: "And don't want to write `return undefined`". Is it acceptable to write `return`?

Comment: If you *don't* have a `return` statement, then why do you want to annotate the return value with anything other than `void`? It's never going to change and doesn't seem to depend on what the function does.

Comment: @CRice tried this in ts playground, and nothing happends, error anyway - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAhmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBbAngMSnJkAKASgC4UoATAU1HkiopQG9gBIYAXxBCA

Comment: @NicholasTower no. Because it returns already by itself.

Comment: @VLAZ because it's type is undefined. And different situations are not about type, they are about situations.

Comment: That's the thing - it's *misleading* to add a type if it has no meaning. `void` perfectly encapsulates "This function doesn't return anything". Saying it returns `undefined` suggests that makes sense. Yet, if it does it because any function always implicitly returns that value and you never rely or influence it, then there really isn't any meaning to that. You're obscuring the fact that the return value shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: @VLAZ There is an exact meaning for me. The undefined means undefined. Not any other meaning or type. And when I mean undefined, I don't want use meaning "nothing or void or promise or any". Everything in my code may rely on this return type. This does not mean that I have to write `return undefined` to allow this "reliance on". I want an exact contract, not "something in some situation".

Comment: `Everything in my code may rely on this return type`  If it always returns `undefined`, what sort of code are you planning to write that will interact with the return value? Like are you going to write code like `if (myFunction() === undefined)`? If you're not going to interact with it, then `void` is the correct type. If you are... well, frankly, i don't know what use that is, so i'd still recommend `void` unless you have an example that demonstrates the point.

Comment: Yet you're introducing "something in some situations". Claiming that a non-returning function actually produces `undefined` is *different* to something like `Array#find` where `undefined` is a valid value from its domain. You've introduced two different meanings for the value in your code. Whereas `void` means a single thing. You further *lose* semantincs for defining your interfaces.

Comment: Most notably you often don't care what a callback produces, so `void` perfectly encapsulates that. Yet if you *demand* it to return `undefined` you lose the ability to pass something like `x => array.push(x)` as a callback and instead have to do `x => { array.push() }` *due to* the dual semantics of `undefined` you've introduced.

Comment: @NicholasTower , @VLAZ , thank you for answers. I can't show all the situations here, where `void` is a big pain. It is a big conversation, not for comments. I understand that maybe everyone think another way and nobody want strict return type, and they want all that meanings and advantages of `void`.

Comment: `I can't show all the situations here` One is all i need. In any event, if you truly understand what `void` means, and you still have decided that `undefined` is better for your case, then you will need to have an explicit return statement. Leaving out a return statement when you've said you'll return something is a bug in most people's code, which is why typescript enforces it.

Comment: @NicholasTower I updated the question to show the use case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would like the compiler to accept that a function whose return type annotation includes `undefined` can implicitly return `undefined` when a code path does not have an explicit `return` statement.  This is a reasonable thing to want but, as you noticed, the language does not currently have this feature as of TypeScript 4.1.  **There is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#36288](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36288).** If you'd like to increase the chances that this will happen, you might want to go there and give it a  and perhaps even describe why your use case requires this or why your code would benefit from it.

Realistically, though, unless you can get a large number of other people to clamor for that issue, it doesn't look like any language maintainers consider it to be a high priority.

The workarounds are ones you presumably dislike, but here they are anyway.  First, explicitly include a `return` statement (without or without `undefined`):

```
function myFunctionReturn(): undefined {
    return; // okay
}
```

Second, use one of the error-suppressing comments like [`//@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) or [`//@ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments):

```
//@ts-ignore
function myFunctionIgnore(): undefined {

}
```

There may be other ways to deal with it, but without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your use cases that *consume* or *use* such `undefined`-returning functions, it's hard to know how to separate this from the `void`-returning functions you are objecting to.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmASgUyhACcwAKASgC5FwATfYGMfOxAbwFgAoRPxYoRJgA3IgD04xHADWAQ1Q8Avjx6SAAlADOAWhgBzMHEE9QkWAhQYsFsAElDx-JRr1GzVh1XclQA)

Comment: Thank you. It is great that not only me think so, but somebody else who opened that request :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

1. Define a type:

```js
type nullable<T> = T | null | undefined
```

2. Define the return type to be `nullable<Type>`, e.g.:

```
const getString = (test: string): nullable<string> => test || undefined
```

Comment: null and undefined are 2 different things, using them interchangeably might lead to a headache

Answer (score -2):

Here you have magic comment:

```js
//@ts-expect-error
function myFunction():undefined {
    
}
```

Comment: You should never use @ts-expect-error unless you actually need an error to be in your code, usually for testing purposes

Comment: @AlexChashin I m not claiming that it is the best solution. OP asks about flags/comments that might be used in such situations. If you read accepted answer , you will find ts-ignore and ts-expect-error. Also, I m not saying that it is safe. It is just a workaround.

Comment: It appears that SO users don't like magic. Either that or there's no magic here.

Comment: @refaelio seems like that :D

Comment: I mean that's just wrong. If anything it should be `@ts-ignore`, because that one at least says what your intention is (which is to turn off the type checking on this line). Imagine they suddenly fixed #36288 and allowed empty returns like this. Your expect-error will suddenly fail.

Comment: @Luxalpa sure, yoy are right