# Define a function that returns a function that returns void

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I don't understand why this gives an error

```
function foo(): () => string {
  return () => 123;
}
```

But this does not

```
function foo(): () => void {
  return () => 123;
}
```

And also this will not give an error as well

```
function foo(): (a: number) => string {
  return () => '123';
}
```

I explicitly type that returned function should accept one argument, then return a function that does not accept any, but TS does not give me any error.

Comment: Because a number can be ignored (`void`), but is not a `string`.

Comment: @Bergi could you  provide more explanation in your comment? It's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Wait, are you asking two questions? You start "and also..." with what appears to be a second question about different code. [Please limit each post to one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  Also, it seems that your second question was edited in after the first one had an answer already. [Please do not add followup questions to existing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions). The right thing to do for your second question is to create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My investigations ended up with a fact that it is impossible to do this with TypesScript, unfortunately.
Here are the links that explain why this unintuitive decision was made

1. [Void type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void)
2. [Assignability of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions)
3. [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

The solution that is closest to the desired functionality is to

1. Type returned function to return undefined

```
function foo(): () => undefined { ... }
```

2. Set on option in `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {"noImplicitReturns": false}
```

3. Explicitly return from the returned function

```
function foo(): () => undefined { 
    return () => { return; }
}
```

Looks a bit ugly but now we can define a function that for sure will return nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a function of type `() => number` to something of type `() => string` clearly is a type error. However, for `void` as a return type, TypeScript is more lenient. From [the handbook on the *Assignability of Functions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions):

> The `void` return type for functions can produce some unusual, but
> expected behavior.
>
> Contextual typing with a return type of `void` does **not** force functions
> to **not** return something. Another way to say this is a contextual
> function type with a `void` return type (`type vf = () => void`), when
> implemented, can return any other value, but it will be ignored.
>
> […]
>
> There is one other special case to be aware of, when a literal
> function definition has a `void` return type, that function must **not**
> return anything.

There's also an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) about it.

Comment: I've read the documentation and they say that: 

This behavior exists so that the following code is valid even though `Array.prototype.push` returns a `number` and the `Array.prototype.forEach` method expects a function with a return type of `void`.

Isn't that more logical then that `Array.prototype.forEach` should expect a function with a return type of `any`

Comment: @fires3as0n Yes. `forEach` expects an argument of type `(value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void`, and TypeScript is designed so that `(value: T) => number` is assignable to that.

Comment: @fires3as0n `any` means "turn of typechecking, ignore errors". Not a good practice. `void` specifically guarantees that `forEach` will not use the return values.

Comment: Still sounds illogical to me. First, looks like using return value of function that returns void does not give an error, only a warning. Second, what about the topic question: How do we define a function that returns a function that *should not return anything*. Is it impossible to do that with Typescript?

Comment: @fires3as0n You can use `() => undefined` for functions that must not return anything.

Comment: @fires3as0n "*using `void` value does not give an error, only a warning*" - how were you using it?

Comment: "how were you using it?"
`function bar(a: () => void): void { const c = a(); }`
This compiles with no error using tsc, only shows warning in my IDE

Comment: "You can use `() => undefined`"
`function foo(): () => undefined { return () => {}; }`
This compiles with an error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Comment: What does "does not give an error, only a warning" mean? TypeScript doesn't have different levels of warning.  Note that I think something like `() => (void | undefined)` or `() => (void & undefined)` might have the effect you're asking for, but can you explain *why* you want this? Can you demonstrate what goes wrong with `function foo(): () => void { return () => 123; }` with a [mre]? I'm just wondering if there's a use case where allowing non-`void` returning functions to be assignable to `void`-returning functions actually causes a real typing problem (instead of just developer surprise).

Comment: I have read more about how Assignability of Functions works and now got the idea on why it works like this, but still find it very confusing that **we can not define the exact signanure of function that should be returned** (sounds like a logical task to do). Because of that it feels like Typescript does not differ between `void` and `any` return types [here is the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gd8ofw). Also none of your suggested solutions works, looks like it is indeed impossible to do this with TS.

Comment: @fires3as0n Have a look at [How to allow a function return type undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691468/how-to-allow-a-function-return-type-undefined) and [the tsc issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36288) linked from there

Comment: In your example even if you get the `void` value and assign it to a variable of type `void`, what can you do with it? You were able to pass it to `console.log` only because the type of `console.log`'s arguments is `...any[]`, basically type checking is disabled for them. If it were `...(string | number)[]` for example, you would not be able to do that: `void` is not assignable to `string | number`. Similarly, you cannot call any methods on `void` whereas on `any` value you can call whatever methods you want and pass them wherever you please